# Selecting and writing paragraphs with matching starting terms

Tags: regex

I have a doc/pdf file which contains legal terms defined in english as well as in translation in another language. The format is like this:

```
Term 1- defined in english
Term 2- defined in english
Term nth- defined in english

Term 1- defined in other language

Term 2- defined in other language

Term nth- defined in other language
```

What I am looking for is to use regex to select paragraphs of terms in english and the translated language and write them one after the other to a text file like this:

```
Term 1- defined in eng

Term 1- defined in other lang

Term 2- defined in eng

Term 2 - defined in other lang.
```

Can you please help me with regex on this?

Comment: Can you post details of what platform you're on using, what technologies, etc? Also, what have you already tried?

Comment: I am on windows 7.i plan to use VB.NET for the regex implementation. I am a beginner in regex and I am not very sure on how to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's a good idea to use Regular Expressions for this. Regular Expressions are used for searching for particular patterns or replacing text in strings based on a particular pattern (usually for changing some format of a string in a linear fashion).

It may be better to simply read them as two arrays then use a `for` loop:

```
var lang1=["One","Two","Three"];
var lang2=["Uno","Dos","Tres"];
var newStr="";
for(var i=0; i<lang1.length; i++){
    newStr+=("Term "+(i+1)+" in lang1 - "+lang1[i]+"\n");
    newStr+=("Term "+(i+1)+" in lang2 - "+lang2[i]+"\n");
}
```

Here is an example in JavaScript: http://jsfiddle.net/U4HbB/